# The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable during app startup

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm getting the following lines on app startup.
Application works fine though:

> Jun 22 18:29:54 Alexeys-iPod-touch xxx[1169] : WARNING: The
>   runtime version supported by this application is unavailable. Jun 22
>   18:29:54 Alexeys-iPod-touch xxx[1169] : Using default
>   runtime: v4.0.30319

What should I do about it (and should I)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just some debug spew we haven't had time to remove yet.

You can safely ignore it.